# Is it possible to change Label font size in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, label, cocos2d-x

Is it possible to change Label font size (like a setString method for text) without creating new object?

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
ui::Button *button = ui::Button::create();
button->setTitleFontName("fonts/FontName.ttf");
button->setTitleFontSize(fontSize);
```

Comment: This is `Button`, not `Label`

Answer (score 0):

No you can't the only thing similiar is that you scale the label.